# Identifying user that just logged in

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a website where if a user will log in, he will see a list of his favorite movies. Currently, I have a user, I know how to make the component for favorite movies, but I have an issue to identify the user, so I cannot see any of the movies.

As I tried to run the request on backend where it works just fine, but I cannot seem to make it into front end.

This is my state in App.js:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tvchannels: [],
            programs: [],
            users: {}
        };
    }
```

This is the request for backend from App.js

```
getFavoriteList(){
        fetch (`https://jobappexam.herokuapp.com/api/users/favorite/:id`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res=>{this.setState({users:res.users})
            });
        this.favoriteStore();
    }
```

This is how I though I might get the id of the user:

```
 getUserId(id){
        let userPosition = this.state.users.find(el => el._id ===id);
        return userPosition;
        console.log(userPosition);
    }
```

And here is the route:

```
<Route exact path ={`/userSchedule`}
                             render = {(props) =>
                                 <FavoriteList {...props}
                                     user = {this.state.users}
                                     favorite={props.match.params.favorite}
                                 />
                             }
                    />
```

I have also tried it this way but it doesn't seem to work either

```
renderUser (props, id) {
        let user = this.getUserId(id);
        return <FavoriteList {...props}
            user={user}
            users={this.state.users}
        />
    }
```

I would like if the website can identify who just logged in and just view his list based on the id it will get. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: `users` is an object or list?

Comment: you can save the user id in the session or cookie after a successful login. For this you only need to return the id after a successful login from the backend to the frontend

Comment: @codekaizer users is a list of objects eg. there is more users with things like password and username and list of favorites